# Turtle Graphics Hexagon Centering

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need some help. I want to center the hexagon into the larger hexagon but I don't now how to do it. Below I have the source code and an image link to the output.

```
import turtle 
polygon = turtle.Turtle() 
num_sides = 6
side_length = 20


move_left = 60

polygon.pensize(2)
polygon.pencolor((245, 176, 66))

for turtle_move in range(num_sides): 
    polygon.forward(side_length) 
    polygon.left(move_left) 


polygon.penup()
polygon.left(2)
polygon.pendown()


side_length2 = 40
move_left2 = 60
```

I want to center the hexagon inside the larger hexagons, but I don't know what to do.

```
for turtle_move in range(num_sides): 
    polygon.forward(side_length2) 
    polygon.left(move_left2)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Before you start drawing the smaller one, turn left by 120, go forward by side_length1 - side_length2 and turn right by 60

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of ways to do this if you read about the geometry of hexagons, eg. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagon):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

NUM_SIDES = 6
SIDE_LENGTH = 20
ANGLE_LEFT = 60

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

for _ in range(NUM_SIDES):
    turtle.forward(SIDE_LENGTH)
    turtle.left(ANGLE_LEFT)

turtle.penup()
turtle.backward(SIDE_LENGTH / 2)
turtle.sety(-SIDE_LENGTH * 3**0.5/2)
turtle.pendown()

for _ in range(NUM_SIDES):
    turtle.forward(SIDE_LENGTH*2)
    turtle.left(ANGLE_LEFT)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

One alternate approach is to use the turtle `circle()` method to draw the hexagons, then it becomes a matter of centering two circles:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

NUM_SIDES = 6
SIDE_LENGTH = 20

circumradius = SIDE_LENGTH

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

for _ in range(2):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(-circumradius)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.circle(circumradius, steps=NUM_SIDES)

    circumradius *= 2

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

I'm assuming by your use of `pencolor((245, 176, 66))` you're using a site like Repl.it or some other non-standard Python turtle implementation, so you may need to adjust the examples above slightly to suit your environment.